# Specify WebMethod in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest

How can to call GetAllData() method defined in the web service and send a XML as its argument using HttpWebRequest in C#?

Comment: What kind of web service?

Comment: asmx type web service

Comment: Then why don't you generate a service reference?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [`Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the request to the desired HTTP verb:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/getalldata");
request.Method = "POST";
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write("<foo>Bar</foo>");
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // do something with the result
}
```

Also there might be easier ways to consume web services depending on their type. If they are SOAP services you could add a Service Reference to your project which will read the metadata of the service and generate a strongly typed proxy which would allow you to directly consume the methods.

If it is a RESTful service you could take advantage of the new [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's built into the framework and which would allow you to directly serialize DTO objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Is this error in code ? asmx type web service. I want to use it using HttpWebRequest. I think we need to use SOAP msg. how ?

Comment: If your service uses SOAP, then you could add Service Reference in Visual Studio. Please read about consuming SOAP services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628652.aspx